# Issue while deploying Azure App Service / API

Tags: azure-api-management, azure-appservice

We have .NET Web service which we developed. We had deployed the Azure App Service, Azure API Management and configured the API to point to the Azure App Service.

When we deployed the code directly to Azure App Service using the Azure Devops and tried calling the API,it gives an error message that the service not found or web app is moved.

Could someone help on how we can deploy .NET code to API using Azure Devops release pipeline.

Thanks

Comment: Many different things could go wrong. You don't expect us to write you a tutorial on how to deploy an app service, don't you? Especially because there are plenty information on the Internet on how to do it. So unless you give us more details, no one will be able to help you.

Comment: Understood, here is the issue i am facing when browsing the API. [EndpointNotFoundException]: There was no channel actively listening at &#39;<<Azure AppService>>/Service.svc/processSIDFile?code=&#39;. This is often caused by an incorrect address URI. Ensure that the address to which the message is sent matches an address on which a service is listening.  I am able to browse the App Service URI

Comment: I was able to fix the issue. the issue was with the web.config.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix the issue. the issue was with the web.config using the link - https://www.beringer.net/beringerblog/wcf-webservice-doesnt-respond-via-https-hosted-microsoft-azure/